# Editing One Sheet is Timestamping Another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this code to timestamp sheet named "Verify"'s Col11 based on the first time (only) Col9 is edited. It will be cleared and reset manually, daily.

The issue i'm having is editing Col9 on any sheet makes Col11 on the "Verify" tab timestamped, on the corresponding row that was edited on another sheet. Example, i'll edit Col9 on "Example Sheet"'s row 89, and Col11 row 89 on sheet "Verify" is timestamped. I'll attach the code i'm using below - thank you!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getSheetByName("Verify");
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var stampCol = sh.getRange(row, 11);
    
  if (col == 9 && !stampCol.getValue()) {
    var tz = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss');
    stampCol.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are "hard coding" the **sh** var to reference the 'Verify' sheet. Combined with your IF statement that doesn't specifically include a sheet name reference.

Try replacing

```
var sh = e.source.getSheetByName("Verify");
```

with:

```
var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
```

And replacing:

```
if (col == 9 && !stampCol.getValue()) {
```

with

```
if (col == 9 && sh.getName() == 'Verify' && !stampCol.getValue()) {
```

Comment: No dice unfortunately, still having the same issue edit - changed sh.getName to match my original sh definition of sh.getSheetByName and it seems to have worked(:

Comment: Ah! I think there's one other issue. Updated my previous answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you! Explanation was helpful as well, still learning

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Verify" && e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    if(e.range.offset(0,2).isBlank()) {
      //e.source.toast("Gate2");
      e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    }
  }
}

function resetCol11() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Verify");
  sh.getRange(2,11,sh.getLastRow() - 1).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you!! Less buggy than my old code. Quick question - how would I set the date/time as an integer instead of a m/d/y format? Can't seem to find any documentation. Including the time in the integer as well would be ideal

Comment: Think I figured out my own question, thank you again!

Comment: The documentation for datetime is in Javascript reference